# Trying to find the signal in an AC line

Tags: ac, oscilloscope, interference, high-pass-filter

I have a medical office call box/light system that is older probably 20 year old and they moved the main panel that the Drs see to know when there are patients waiting and since they moved it, it is intermittently not working. The system uses a signal that is transmitted over the AC connection/plug.
I am new to oscilloscopes but purchased one to see if I could observe if the signal is too weak in the new location (it’s about 250 feet from where it was originally) or if it’s getting too much interference.
I have found that the system needs to be on its own circuit and have a 2700 UH choke installed on the circuit feed but that’s about all I can come up with since apparently the manufacture has gone out of business. They do still have a website but only very limited information and no schematics.
http://www.varitronics.com/ts-cs2install-nc.htm

My problem seems to be when I look at the pattern all I can identify is the 60hz signal and don’t see any changes when energizing one of the boxes and would like to know if anyone has any suggestions for blocking out the 120V 60Hz signal so I can see the signal that is used to operate these boxes over the 120V line. I believe I need a high pass filter but not sure what components I would need to achieve blocking the unwanted signal but still be able to pass the triggering signal I am looking for to identify the problem.
Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Are all components powered by a single AC phase?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a reverse engineering, modification, or repair question. Please be aware that such questions must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being discussed, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. More information can be found here: [Is asking how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Comment: Does the scope have a LF reject option on the channel? This would normally be a high pass filter at around 50KHz. Would reject the 60Hz without need for an external filter.

Comment: How do you use the oscilloscope on mains ac? That can be dangerous, especially if you are unexperienced.